# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to connect MongoDB database via hibernate with spring-boot. While trying to connect to MongoDB, I'm getting below error. Please help me to connect via hibernate. In my build.gradle, I have "hibernate-ogm-mongodb" dependency only.

Gradle :

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate.ogm', name: 'hibernate-ogm-mongodb', version: '5.4.1.Final'
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MyMongoDB"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider"
                value="MONGODB" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database"
                value="testdb" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host"
                value="localhost" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port"
                value="27017" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database"
                value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Configuration file :

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyMongoDB");
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

**Description:**
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.hibernate.ogm.boot.impl.OgmSessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(OgmSessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:56)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
void org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(org.hibernate.boot.spi.BootstrapContext, org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataImplementor, org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions)
```

The method's class, org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Myuser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.12.Final/7813daed21576920450443097d69823245d112d2/hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/Myuser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.12.Final/7813daed21576920450443097d69823245d112d2/hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar
```

Action:

```
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl
```

Comment: You dont need session factory in spring boot until its necessary. what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate OGM 5.4.1.Final requires Hibernate ORM 5.3.6.Final.

Some of the dependencies in the project are not aligned.

Comment: Thanks Davide. I have used hibernate-core version of 5.3.6 in my build.gradle as mentioned, now I can able to connect my mongodb via hibernate. By Internally, The hibernate-ogm-mongodb took the hibernate-core version of 5.4.12.Final. Even I tried to use hibernate-core version of 5.3.16.Final, it's connecting. Thank you.